# lseek beyond EOF on an MTD

Tags: c, file, lseek

The manual page for `lseek()` says:

> lseek() allows the file offset to be set beyond the end of the file
>   (but this does not  change  the  size  of  the
>          file).   If  data  is  later written at this point, subsequent reads of the data in the gap (a "hole") return null
>          bytes ('\0') until data is actually written into the gap.

At the error section it says:

> **EINVAL** whence  is  not  valid.   Or:  the resulting file offset would
>   be negative, or beyond the end of a seekable device.

I'm unsure how to interpret the `lseek` manual page as it doesn't mention MTD.

Assuming that the `MTD` has been opened with read and write permission, how would `lseek()` respond when seeking past EOF when `whence` is `SEEK_SET` for MTD's?

Comment: What is an MTD?

Comment: What it's describing generally only works on ordinary files, not devices.

Comment: Memory techonology device, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Technology_Device

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix file and device concepts. The manual page is perfectly clear: you can seek past the end of the file, but not to the point that the file would become larger than what the device can host.

Example: you have a 128Mb device with only an empty file in it. You can open the file and seek to any position < 128Mb,  because a subsequent write() would make the file grow. But surely you can not seek > 128Mb, because a subsequent write() will surely fail, and this is already known at the time of the seek.

Now, to the MTD device. The MTD is an abstraction layer that maps a (flash) hardware device into a file. Given this, the file exposes both the behaviors of a file and a device, something like a file big exactly as the device it refers to, hence seeking past the end of file equals seeking past the end of the device. In this case another curiosity comes to my mind: what if we try to *truncate* that file? I suppose to know already the answer...

Comment: Looking closer at the manual page it does say if I `lseek` beyond end of a seekable device it will return `EINVAL`

Comment: Yes, but you seek on files, not devices. And if it happens that a file refers to a device, well it is still a file.